# How can i get mouse clicked cell value in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using a web application gridview on my page...
I want to get the selected(mouse clicked) cell text value & also which event i want to use?..!

Comment: there are many ways to do this, for an example of a client side solution go here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1396348.aspx/1 and scroll down to the answer marked as the best in green.

Answer (score 0):

use [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event.

Comment: Hi Primoz...! Thanks for your reply... i tried  the SelectedIndexChanged event,but its not fired when i click one cell in gridview using mouse..!

Comment: Hm, strange. Try what Manthan Dave suggested. Also, maybe you need to set allow selection property first.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about cell, but you can definitely get the selected row. First of all, set the allow selection property to true. Second, go in events and there should be an event called `SelectedIndexChanged`This would allow you to do something when the selected index is changed. Then, using
`gridvidew1.Rows[gridView1.selectedindex]`
you will be able to get the selected row. User can select the row by using the select link placed automatically against each row.

Hope this helps,